# Assign a value conditionally after array is set with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

If I wanted to do something like this:

```
<?php

$numbers = array(

    "a_pos" => 0,
    "b_pos" => 2,
    "c_pos" => 3

    );


if ($numbers["a_pos"] == 0)
    $a_pos_txt = TRUE;

if ($numbers["b_pos"] == 0)
    $b_pos_txt = TRUE;

if ($numbers["c_pos"] == 0)
    $c_pos_txt = TRUE;

?>
```

(Just assign `TRUE` to `$a_pos_txt` because it is equal to `0`)

What would be that smart way to do it? I´m sure there must be a way to do it in "one step".

Thanks in advance!!

Please ask for any needed clarificarion.

Comment: I, for one, don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Steve: I want to set a variable $a_pos_txt to TRUE only if a_pos is equal to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, as there may be a better approach overall, but to answer your question, you can skip the `if` statements like so:

```
$a_pos_txt = $numbers["a_pos"] == 0;
$b_pos_txt = $numbers["b_pos"] == 0;
$c_pos_txt = $numbers["c_pos"] == 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but this was not what I was trying to do, I want to set a variable $a_pos_txt to TRUE only if a_pos is equal to 0.

Comment: @Trufa, that's what happens, otherwise it will be set to false.

Comment: OMG! I was not seeing it!!! That is a fantastic idea, thank you so much and sorry I could not understand it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the **$numbers** is an array, you can do a loop to avoid repeating the similar pattern,
such as

```
foreach ($numbers as $key=>$val)
{
  if ($val==0)
  {
    ${$key."_txt"}=true;
  }
}
```